# Trigger Azure logic app on resource creation

Tags: azure, automation, azure-logic-apps

I'm working on an Azure Logic app that should trigger when a new resource is created.
However, if I trigger the app based on a webhook using monitor alerts or an event subscription, I run into the problem of each creation event will have 2 identical events with all the output being identical which means I can't filter it out and therefore triggers the logic app twice.

If there a different route around to just get the app to trigger once?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the multiple events are because the event type for both create or update is the same as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-subscriptions).

One way to workaround this would be to keep track of `resourceId`s touched by your Logic App, OR add a tag to your resource which signals that it has been touched. This way you wouldn't need an extra store for this metadata.

Comment: Just to clarify, it first creates the resource and then updates it then? otherwise, I can't seem to figure out why there should be 2 events.
If so, it doesn't seem to make sense that the second event is fired, about 10 minutes later than the first one, when the resource is created with the correct settings